# How to save data for edit page in Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade

My create page is in `vue.js`. So, I called the vue.js file using component. Now for edit page also i did the same. I just called vue component in blade. How i will save data for the edit page. Anyone can help me?

```
@extends('layouts.main')

@section('content')

<div class="justpaddingside" role="main">
    <div class="row w-100 Bfont ">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="havence-content">
                <div class="havence-content-header"></div>
                   <div class="row w-100">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="pillbutton bge">
                                <div class="x_title" >
                                    <img src="https://img.icons8.com/bubbles/50/000000/important-mail.png" class="rounded float-left" >  
                                    <h2 class="p-3 font-weight-bold">Edit Email Reminder</h2> 
                                    <h4 class="text-right">{{date('d-m-Y')}}</h4>
                                    <h5 class="text-right">{{date('H:i:s')}}</h5>
                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                    <div class="x_content p-5">

                                    <div id="app">
                                        <a class= "float-right" href="{{ route('havence.automail.index') }}"> 
                                            <img src="https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/close-window.png">
                                        </a>
                                        <email-component
                                            {{-- email_creation_link="{{ route('email.create') }}"
                                            email_index_route="{{ route('havence.automail.index') }}" --}}
                                            email_edit_route="{{ route('havence.automail.edit',['id'=>$mailTemplates->id]) }}"
                                            :conditions="{{ json_encode($conditions) }}"
                                            :modules="{{ json_encode($modules) }}"
                                            :mailtemplates="{{json_encode($mailTemplates)}}"
                                        >
                                        </email-component>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success buttonCS col-md-12" data-dismiss="modal">Update</button>


                                    </div>



                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection

@push('stylesheets')
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.16/datatables.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/css/select2.min.css">
@endpush

@push('scripts')
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.16/datatables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert2@7.19.3/dist/sweetalert2.all.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.min.js"></script>
@endpush

@section('page-js')
    <script>

        var typingTimer=null;                //timer identifier
        var doneTypingInterval = 200;  //time in ms, 5 second for example

    </script>
@endsection
```

I attach my edit page code over here. Please help me on this.

I kept searching for this but couldn't find an answer that will make this clear.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By sending data from form to PHP using POST method. Submit the form or can use API.

Reference Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l0RB0VkvEIE

Comment: this method i implement for saving data for create page.Do you know other method ?or can give me an example?

Comment: This same way it will work for edit as well. In edit instead of Priting content on page you populate fields and submit the form to update the data from backend. Adding Showing Editing has a terminology named CRUD. Check this for more informaiton: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jMG4UgGB7W8